# Drawing collision detection boxes

Tags: c#, monogame

So I have a `TileSprite` class that makes a `TileSprite`object with a collision box in it named `bCollisionRect`:

```
public TileSprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize, Point currentFrame)
        : base (textureImage, position, frameSize, currentFrame)
{
    bCollisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + collisionOffSet, (int)position.Y + collisionOffSet, frameSize.X - (collisionOffSet * 2), frameSize.Y - (collisionOffSet * 2));
}
```

But when I try to draw the collision boxes (to test collision detection), it doesn't draw the box. I tried using this:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    // This is what I tried:
    spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage, bCollisionRect, Color.White);

    // base.Draw draws the texture (.Draw method from another abstract class)
    base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
}
```

I use this line of code in another class to draw my tiles (pure for testing!):

```
tilename.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"?  Is the sprite drawn at a different location than expected? Is the sprite not drawn at all?

Comment: Not drawn at all, sorry for the confusion

Comment: frameSize.X - (collisionOffSet * 2)   Are you sure this is not resulting in 0?  What is collisionOffset?  This seems incorrect to me.   Try setting a new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, 100,100)   and see if it draws.

Comment: I think I found my problem. I use `textureImage` but that just draws the tile again(I saw this when I used your values, because I saw a little tile, the same as the tile I drew). So do I need to use a texture for the collision box as `textureImage`?

Comment: Yep, use a blank texture for debugging purposes.  I typically have a 1x1 white texture I generate at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to create a blank texture at runtime (after discussing with you via comments above):

```
Texture2D blankTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
Color[] color = new Color[1];
color[0] = Color.White;
blankTexture.SetData(color);
```

Then your draw call... specify a color if you want to tint it:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(blankTexture, bCollisionRect, Color.Red);
```